# & cut off in directory path

Tags: php, get, directory, message-passing

I'm passing a folder name and path via a $_GET. All is fine until I pass a folder name containing and (&) ampersand then the folder name is cut short. i.e folder name test & replace is shorted to 'test '.
Have tried str_repalce, htmlentites, htmlspecialchars

```
$dir_path = $_GET['path'].$_GET['folder'];
```

The whole code:

```
    <div class="panel-body" style="font-size:14px">
<?php
            if(isset($_GET['path'])){
    $dir_path = $_GET['path'].$_GET['folder']."/";
    echo "full path = ".$dir_path."<br>folder = ".$Folder;
}else{
    $dir_path = PUBLICPATH."/Folderholder/".$branch."/"; // branch url to that branchs folders and in $_GET['folder'];
}
//$dir = opendir($dir_path);
$mappath = str_replace(PUBLICPATH."/Folderholder/","",$dir_path);
 echo "<p><i class='fa fa-sitemap'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>".$mappath."</b></i></p>\n"; ?>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
<?php
 echo "<button onclick='goBack()' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'>Return</button><P>\n";
?>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6"> 
<?php
if(parent::$UM->get('Level') !== 'User' and $branch !== 'Main-Admin'){ 
echo "<a href='uploadfrm?path=".$dir_path."' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'>Upload to this folder</a>";
}elseif(parent::$UM->get('Level') == 'Main-Admin'){
echo "<a href='uploadfrm?path=".$dir_path."' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'>Upload to this folder</a>";
}   
?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row"><div class="col-md-12">&nbsp;</div></div>
    <table width="70%">
<?php
$files = scandir($dir_path);htmls
foreach ($files as $file)
 {
     if($file != "." && $file != "..")
     {
        echo "<tr>\n";
        if(is_dir($dir_path.$file)){ 
        echo "<td><i class='fa fa-folder'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='".BASEURL."Folderholder/userdash?path=".$dir_path."&folder=".$file."'>$file</a></td>\n";
        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>\n";
        }else{
        echo "<td><i class='fa fa-download'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$file."</td>\n<td><a href='http://downloadfolder/download1.php?file=".$dir_path.$file."' target='_Blank'>Download</a></td>\n";  
        }//change path as required
        echo "</tr>\n";
     }
 }

            ?>  
        </table>
        </section>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `&` character is used to separate key=value pairs in the query string.

When you generate the query string you should express it as an escape sequence: `%26`.

How you do that depends on how you are generating the query string in the first place.

---

You've tagged this [php](/questions/tagged/php), but the PHP code you have shared is **reading** the data. You haven't shown us the code for generating it, but assuming that *is* still PHP:

To generate it in PHP you would normally use [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php):

```
$query = http_build_query(Array( path => "example&example", folder => "example&example" ));
```

Answer (score 0):

[`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) should do the trick. It is specifically used for passing parameters to a URL to use as variables, as you are doing in your GETs.

Answer (score 0):

Though previous answers in this thread are not incorrect, please also consider using [rawurlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) as it will generate a more standards compliant ([RFC 3986](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986.html)) URI. [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) triggers the legacy encoding where spaces are replaced by plus-signs. (Anyone remember that?)

Answer (score 0):

To stop the cut off of the folder name.
Two coding changes $dir_path = $_GET['path'].$_GET['folder']."/"; changed to

```
$dir_path = $_GET['path'].rawurldecode($_GET['folder'])."/";
```

and `echo "<td><i class='fa fa-folder'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='".BASEURL."Folderholder/userdash?path=".$dir_path."&folder=".$file."'>$file</a></td>\n";`
changed to

```
echo "<td><i class='fa fa-folder'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='".BASEURL."Folderholder/userdash?path=".$dir_path."&folder=".rawurlencode($file)."'>$file</a></td>\n";

<div class="panel-body" style="font-size:14px">
<?php
            if(isset($_GET['path'])){
    $dir_path = $_GET['path'].$_GET['folder']."/";
}else{
    $dir_path = PUBLICPATH."/Folderholder/".$branch."/"; // branch url to that branchs folders and in $_GET['folder'];
}
//$dir = opendir($dir_path);
$mappath = str_replace(PUBLICPATH."/Folderholder/","",$dir_path);
 echo "<p><i class='fa fa-sitemap'>&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>".$mappath."</b></i></p>\n"; ?>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
<?php
 echo "<button onclick='goBack()' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'>Return</button><P>\n";
?>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6"> 
<?php
if(parent::$UM->get('Level') !== 'User' and $branch !== 'Main-Admin'){ 
echo "<a href='uploadfrm?path=".$dir_path."' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'>Upload to this folder</a>";
}elseif(parent::$UM->get('Level') == 'Main-Admin'){
echo "<a href='uploadfrm?path=".$dir_path."' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'>Upload to this folder</a>";
}   
?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row"><div class="col-md-12">&nbsp;</div></div>
    <table width="70%">
<?php
$files = scandir($dir_path);htmls
foreach ($files as $file)
 {
     if($file != "." && $file != "..")
     {
        echo "<tr>\n";
        if(is_dir($dir_path.$file)){ 
        echo "<td><i class='fa fa-folder'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='".BASEURL."Folderholder/userdash?path=".$dir_path."&folder=".$file."'>$file</a></td>\n";
        echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>\n";
        }else{
        echo "<td><i class='fa fa-download'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$file."</td>\n<td><a href='http://downloadfolder/download1.php?file=".$dir_path.$file."' target='_Blank'>Download</a></td>\n";  
        }//change path as required
        echo "</tr>\n";
     }
 }

            ?>  
        </table>
        </section>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `urlencode` to encode the url like:

```
$encodedURL = urlencode ('Your url');
```

Explanation: `urlencode` will encode the special characters to their entity values and than use it.

Comment: "and before using it, decode it like" — Don't do that. PHP will decode it automatically before populating `$_GET`

Comment: `$encodedURL = string urlencode ( string $str )` — That's a syntax error. You can't just stick an assignment on the front of the PHP manual's explanation as to variable types.

Comment: And `'Your url'` should be just the variable you want to insert into the query string. And the output is the escaped version of that, not the whole URL. If you put the whole URL in then you'll escape all the special characters, not just the ones you want to be treated as data.